# Monitoring performance of server using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have a request off a customer to write a piece of software (console app or service) that will live on the server and monitor the general performance (cpu usage, memory usage and disk usage) and report on any long periods of high usage.

Is this possible in C#/.NET?

Comment: What is wrong with the built-in performance monitoring, analysis and alert functionality http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771692(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @rene - How do access these from C#?

Comment: Does customer really need such a thing written from scratch, or could it use existing software for this, like [nagios](http://www.nagios.org)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace to issue [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) queries and report on the results.

> Provides access to a rich set of management information and management events about the system, devices, and applications instrumented to the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) infrastructure. Applications and services can query for interesting management information (such as how much free space is left on the disk, what is the current CPU utilization, which database a certain application is connected to, and much more), using classes derived from ManagementObjectSearcher and ManagementQuery, or subscribe to a variety of management events using the ManagementEventWatcher class. The accessible data can be from both managed and unmanaged components in the distributed environment.

Also see this MSDN Magazine article:

[WMI and .NET: System.Management Lets You Take Advantage of WMI APIs within Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302051.aspx)

Comment: I find that WMI Queries are really slow.

Comment: @Derek - better slow answers than none.